# Can I fill a PDF template from a Java app? How?

Tags: java, xml, swing, pdf, pdf-generation

I made a fillable template for a PDF document, and I'm collecting the data using a Java application. I was wondering if I can fill this template with the data I have in the application, then save the file. This data can be Integers and Strings.
Is it by any means possible? If not, are there alternatives to this?
Thank you very much.

Comment: You can do it with [iText](http://itextpdf.com/) or [JasperReports](http://community.jaspersoft.com/project/jasperreports-library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/) is a very neat library to manipulate PDF in Java. [PDAcroForm](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/interactive/form/PDAcroForm.html) is the class representing forms in document.

PDFBox is well documented, you should have no difficulty to fill a form.

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need.